# extjs 4.2 - replace substring, but avoid changing tags

Tags: regex, string, extjs, replace, extjs4.2

In a given string, e.g. `"This <TERM>is</TERM> my question <TERM>for</TERM> you"`, I need to replace a substring.

Goal: surround substring with `<MARK>`-Tags for highlighting.

**Example**:

substring: 'e'

desired result: `This <TERM>is</TERM> my qu<mark>e</mark>stion <TERM>for</TERM> you`

actual result: `This <T<mark>E</mark>RM>is</T<mark>E</mark>RM> my qu<mark>e</mark>stion <T<mark>E</mark>RM>for</T<mark>E</mark>RM> you`

How can I prevent the pseudoTags `<TERM>` and `</TERM>` from beeing changed?

Until now, I used this:

according to my example, filterValue would be substring 'e'

```
var filterStartTag = '<mark>';
var filterEndTag = '</mark>';
var replaceFilterValue = filterStartTag + filterValue + filterEndTag;
value = value.replace(new RegExp(filterValue, 'gi'), replaceFilterValue);
```

I need to find a solution where also substrings like "t", "te", "erm" (and so on) can properly be replaced.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
    value.replace(/(e)+(?![^<]*>)/g, "$1");

The `(e)` is what is interpreted as `$1` for your replacement, and can be replaced with any Regex that matches what you need (keep it surrounded by parentheses to allow for the `$1` replacement).  So, you could also do it like this, to be more dynamic:

```
var r = new RegExp("(" + filterValue + ")+(?![^<]*>)", "gi");
value.replace(r, "<mark>$1</mark>");
```

Essentially, this is saying to match anything in the first parentheses, unless it is surrounded by tags `(?![^<]*>)`.

Comment: you really saved my day! I was racking my brain all day when suddenly I saw your answer. Thank you very much, it seems to work perfect! There's still so much to learn for me, seems as if RegEx should also be a part of it ;)! Thank you very much!

Comment: one problem still exists: if 'n' in Lausanne should be replaced, only the first occurence is replaced -> Lausa<mark>n</mark> and not as I would need it: Lausa<mark>n</mark><mark>n</mark>e (also usable: Lausa<mark>nn</mark>). Can you help me again, please?

Comment: omg... stupid me: removing the "+" did it: `var r = new RegExp("(" + filterValue + ")(?![^<]*>)", "gi");` :)